is there a way I can output my brush strokes to two images at once?
I'm trying to figure out a way in which I can paint onto two different textures at the same time.
Currently trying to make a plugin for blender using bpy.
I'd like to find a way to catch the pixel data that is being changed when I paint in texture paint mode, and copy those pixels, modify them and apply to another texture image at the same time.
basically want to do something like this
 myimagepixels = bpy.data.images["myimage"].pixels
 secondimagepixel;
 #listen for changes to these pixels in myimagepixels
 #which is where im stuck, i can't figure out how to listen for these changes, and then pass the relevant pixels to the function
 def onPixelUpdate(pixels):
   #invert colors or something
   secondimagepixels = pixels


